# XSL/FO skip a value in Choose statement

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, apache-fop

I'm trying to figure out a way to skip a value in my XSL template. The value is in the select="ID" tag called "Editor". I am trying to skip a specific value in a Choose when statement and I'm not sure that's possible.

```
        <xsl:param name="caption">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Description"><xsl:value-of select="Description" /></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="ID" /></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:param>
```

How could I get an xsl statement in the above logic to skip a value in the ID called Editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:param name="caption">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Description"><xsl:value-of select="Description" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="ID[not(. = 'Editor')]" /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:param>
```

*"The value of any `<ID>` that is not equal to `'Editor'`."*

So if there only is one `<ID>`, this selects 1 or 0 nodes.

Comment: that's how you do it... Thank you so much